# Python: compact/one liner for the for loop

Tags: python, xml

I have the following code that works and gives me the expected output.

```
#!/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as e
tree = e.parse("Document.XML")
root = tree.getroot()
vals=[]
```

Can the following part of the code be a one-liner or any more compact ?

```
for ch in root.findall('arch'):
    for gc in ch.findall('pro'):
        vals.append(gc.get('label'))
```

The libxml2 version I have, doesn't support `xpath`, please don't suggest that option. The XMl file looks like this:

```
<projects>
  <arch name="arch1">
    <pro label="A1" type="B1" state="C1"/>
    ....
  </arch>
  ....
</projects>
```

Comment: Yes, you could, but I would advise against it.  There's nothing unreadable about this code.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, use a list comprehension with two loops:

```
vals = [gc.get('label') for ch in root.findall('arch') for gc in ch.findall('pro')]
```

Comment: Or, of course, you could go half-way there with an explicit outer loop, but the inner loop replaced by the simple comprehension `vals.append(gc.get('label') for gc in ch.findall('pro'))`. It's probably worth typing all three up and seeing which one is most readable to you (and your coworkers/fellow contributors/etc., if relevant).

Answer (score 1):

Using [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) you can probably just do something like

```
data = xmltodict.parse("Document.XML")
val = data['arch']['pro']['@label']
```

You'll have to play with my pseudocode to add the list comprehension for multiple `val`s, but the above should illustrate the basic usage (and see the git page).  [Bruno Rocha](http://rochacbruno.com.br/xmltodict-python-module-that-makes-working-with-xml-feel-like-you-are-working-with-json/) recently blogged about xmltodict.

Comment: How do I get the `xmltodict` module ? Is this available in pyton 2.x ?

Comment: `pip install xmltodict`